# How to find all PointerIds for CoreWindow

Tags: c++, input, windows-runtime

Is there a way to get all of the PointerIDs that might be used in the CoreWindow::PointerPressed??

I know that I can get the ID for the Mouse by using:

```
// This is wrong, see the comment below.
MouseCursorID = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->PointerCursor->Id
```

**EDIT:**
The above block of code gets the 'Resource Id' for CoreCursor.  It IS NOT the same thing as the pointer ID!

So how would one go about finding the different Ids for the various pointers?  I am especially interested in this because I want to be able to discern input from two different mice, and being able to identify them before receiving events would be a great help.

Comment: There is no fixed set of possible IDs. In the case of touch, a new ID is generated each time a finger comes in contact with the screen.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice because the mouse IDs stay constant.  After some more experimentation, I also noticed that the IDs for pen inputs will change, but only after additional touch input(s) have been registered.  Anyway, I'm going to summarize all of this in my own answer (I can't vote for a comment) if you don't feel like it.

Comment: Go ahead and write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

They will appear as necessary in the various pointer event arguments -- see [PointerEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.pointereventargs.aspx).

You don't know ahead of time how many theoretical pointers there might be. What's the reason that you want to know?

Comment: I have updated my question, including why I would want to know.  Also, it is good to know these things for the sake of pure technical know how.